# how to change user login page in drupal

Tags: drupal, redirect, authentication

When a user types in the address bar www.mysite.com/user I want to redirect to users/user if signed and when is not signed to redirect to www.mysite.com/login.

Comment: that is exactly what happens except it's user/login (unless you added an alias for that page)?

Comment: ok i know but i create custom page(page-login.tpl.php) now i have tow page for login www.mysite.com/user and www.mysite.com/login with deterrent style i want user can not login in user or when user type www.mysite.com/user don't display

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can implement hook_init() in a custom module, check if the user is logged in or not and then do the redirect with drupal_goto() to user/$user->uid (Do not use the alias, drupal_goto() will look that one up for you) or to user/login.

```
function yourmodule_init() {
  global $user;
  if ($_GET['q'] == 'user') {
    if ($user->uid > 0) {
      drupal_goto('user/' . $user->uid);
    }
    else {
      drupal_goto('user/login');
    }
  }
}
```

You can also do it fancier and override the page callback of 'user' with hook_menu_alter().

Comment: That will redirect the user on every page load.

Comment: Fixed, just add a condition to prevent it from running on every page ;)